# response status coming as 200 in graphql even if I send 400 Bad Request Exception

Tags: graphql, nestjs, express-graphql, nestjs-graphql

In my `nestjs` application, I am throwing `BadReuqestException` for one `graphql` endpoint. But in the response I still see 200 Ok
I tried throwing `GraphQLError` also but not working.

```
formatError: (error) => {
        const originalError = error.extensions?.originalError;
        if (!originalError) {
          return {
            message: error.message,
            statusCode: error.extensions?.code,
          };
        }
        return {
          message: originalError['message'],
          error: originalError['error'],
          statusCode: originalError['statusCode'],
        };
      },
```

Custom exception  handler

```
@Catch()
export class CustomExceptionFilter
  implements ExceptionFilter, GqlExceptionFilter
{
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response: any = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();

    const gqlHost = GqlArgumentsHost.create(host);
    const info = gqlHost.getInfo<GraphQLResolveInfo>();

    const status = exception.getStatus
      ? exception.getStatus()
      : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const errorResponse = {
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      error: exception.message || null,
    };

    // This is for REST petitions
    if (request) {
      const error = {
        ...errorResponse,
        path: request.url,
        method: request.method,
      };

      Logger.error(
        `${request.method} ${request.url}`,
        JSON.stringify(error),
        'ExceptionFilter'
      );

      response.status(exception.getStatus()).json({
        message: errorResponse.error,
        statusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        timestamp: errorResponse.timestamp,
      });
    } else {
      // This is for GRAPHQL petitions
      const error = {
        ...errorResponse,
        type: info.parentType,
        field: info.fieldName,
      };

      Logger.error(
        `${info.parentType} ${info.fieldName}`,
        JSON.stringify(error),
        'ExceptionFilter'
      );
      response.status(exception.getStatus()).json({
        message: errorResponse.error,
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: errorResponse.timestamp,
      });
      // return exception;
      return errorResponse;
    }
  }
}
```

Help me find a solution which I can use to send 400 as response status code 401 or any respective exception status.
Note: In the response body status code is coming, but I want status code reflected in main status code where it's showing 200 Ok even if response body has 400 Bad Request.